# Third Order Differential Equation with Variable Coefficient

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

I have the following third-order differential equation:-
\begin{align*}
&(x+1)\frac{d^3y}{dx^3} + 3\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=0
\\ \\
& \text{such that, $y(1) = \frac{1}{2}$} 
\end{align*}

I have to show that the solution to the differential equation as series of ascending powers of $(x-1)$, up to and including the term in $(x-1)^3$ is,
\begin{align*}
y \approx \frac{1}{2} + \frac{3}{4}(x-1) + \frac{1}{8}(x-1)^2 - \frac{1}{16}(x-1)^3
\end{align*}

Can anyone help me solve this?

Comment: Start reducing the order

Comment: Perhaps your textbook discusses power-series solutions for DEs.

Comment: Can you share some good resource using which I can solve this? Thanks

Comment: This is a third-order DE, for its solution you need 3 initial or boundary conditions. You only wrote one. Is it to be assumed that the first and second derivative are zero at $x=1$? Or that the solution should be finite at $x=-1$? Or did you write the equation wrong and the first factor is actually $(x-1)$, so that the one initial condition already includes boundedness at the singularity?

Comment: Just like how we guess $y=e^{rx}$ for constant coefficient, linear DEs, you should guess $y=(x+1)^r$ and solve for $r$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Here is the exact question:- 
https://imgur.com/fkeABxN

Comment: @NinadMunshi Can you help me solve this? I am new to this topic.

Comment: I just did. Do what I suggested and show in the post how far you got with plugging in that suggestion.

Comment: So the power series solution is for $(x+1)y'+y-2x=0$. This is an important difference, as here you indeed only need one initial condition. If you have done part (a), then you have an easy way to compute $y'(1)$, $y''(1)$ and $y'''(1)$, so that (b) is just assembling the Taylor polynomial. /// Note that direct integration of the original equation gives $(x+1)y(x)=x^2+C$

Answer (score 1):

There are different methods to solve the ODE. I think the nicest way would be via order reduction:

Substitute $\frac{\operatorname{d}^{2}y\left( x \right)}{\operatorname{d}^{2}x} = v\left( x \right)$ aka $\frac{\operatorname{d}^{3}y\left( x \right)}{\operatorname{d}^{3}x} = \frac{\operatorname{d}v\left( x \right)}{\operatorname{d}x}$:

$$
\begin{align*}
\left( x + 1 \right) \cdot \frac{\operatorname{d}^{3}y\left( x \right)}{\operatorname{d}^{3}x} + 3 \cdot \frac{\operatorname{d}^{2}y\left( x \right)}{\operatorname{d}^{2}x} &= 0\\
\left( x + 1 \right) \cdot \frac{\operatorname{d}v\left( x \right)}{\operatorname{d}x} + 3 \cdot v\left( x \right) &= 0\\
\end{align*}
$$

With a bit of rearranging we would get this:
$$
\begin{align*}
\left( x + 1 \right) \cdot \frac{\operatorname{d}v\left( x \right)}{\operatorname{d}x} + 3 \cdot v\left( x \right) &= 0\\
\left( x + 1 \right) \cdot \frac{\operatorname{d}v\left( x \right)}{\operatorname{d}x} &= -3 \cdot v\left( x \right)\\
\frac{\frac{\operatorname{d}v\left( x \right)}{\operatorname{d}x}}{v\left( x \right)} &= -3 \cdot \frac{1}{x + 1}\\
\int \frac{\frac{\operatorname{d}v\left( x \right)}{\operatorname{d}x}}{v\left( x \right)}\, \operatorname{d}x &= \int -3 \cdot \frac{1}{x + 1}\, \operatorname{d}x\\
\int \frac{\frac{\operatorname{d}v\left( x \right)}{\operatorname{d}x}}{v\left( x \right)}\, \operatorname{d}x &= -3 \cdot \int \frac{1}{x + 1}\, \operatorname{d}x\\
\end{align*}
$$

Now if we use $\int \left( \frac{\operatorname{d}^{n + 1}v\left( x \right)}{\operatorname{d}^{n + 1}x} \right) / \left( \frac{\operatorname{d}^{n}v\left( x \right)}{\operatorname{d}^{n}x} \right)\, \operatorname{d}x = \ln\left( \frac{\operatorname{d}^{n}v\left( x \right)}{\operatorname{d}^{n}x} \right)$ where $n = 0$ and $\int \frac{1}{a \cdot x + b}\, \operatorname{d}x = \frac{1}{a} \cdot \ln\left( a \cdot x + b \right)$ where $a = 1$ and $b = 1$ we get:
$$
\begin{align*}
\int \frac{\frac{\operatorname{d}v\left( x \right)}{\operatorname{d}x}}{v\left( x \right)}\, \operatorname{d}x &= \int -3 \cdot \frac{1}{x + 1}\, \operatorname{d}x\\
\ln\left( v\left( x \right) \right) &= -3 \cdot \ln\left( x + 1 \right) + c_{1}\\
v\left( x \right) &= \exp\left( -3 \cdot \ln\left( x + 1 \right) + c_{1} \right)\\
v\left( x \right) &= \left( \exp\left( \ln\left( x + 1 \right) \right) \right)^{-3} \cdot \exp\left( c_{1} \right)\\
v\left( x \right) &= \left( x + 1 \right)^{-3} \cdot \exp\left( c_{1} \right)\\
\end{align*}
$$

Now Resubstitute $\frac{\operatorname{d}^{2}y\left( x \right)}{\operatorname{d}^{2}x} = v\left( x \right)$ and get:
$$
\begin{align*}
v\left( x \right) &= \left( x + 1 \right)^{-3} \cdot \exp\left( c_{1} \right)\\
\frac{\operatorname{d}^{2}y\left( x \right)}{\operatorname{d}^{2}x} &= \left( x + 1 \right)^{-3} \cdot \exp\left( c_{1} \right)\\
\frac{\operatorname{d}y\left( x \right)}{\operatorname{d}x} &= \int \left( x + 1 \right)^{-3} \cdot \exp\left( c_{1} \right)\, \operatorname{d}x\\
y\left( x \right) &= \int \int \left( x + 1 \right)^{-3} \cdot \exp\left( c_{1} \right)\, \operatorname{d}x\, \operatorname{d}x\\
y\left( x \right) &= \exp\left( c_{1} \right) \cdot \int \int \left( x + 1 \right)^{-3}\, \operatorname{d}x\, \operatorname{d}x\\
\end{align*}
$$

Via using $\int f\left( a \cdot x + b \right)\, \operatorname{d}x = \frac{1}{a} \cdot F\left( a \cdot x + b \right)$ we get:
$$
\begin{align*}
y\left( x \right) &= \exp\left( c_{1} \right) \cdot \int \int \left( x + 1 \right)^{-3}\, \operatorname{d}x\, \operatorname{d}x\\
y\left( x \right) &= \exp\left( c_{1} \right) \cdot \int -\frac{1}{2} \cdot \left( x + 1 \right)^{-2} + c_{2}\, \operatorname{d}x\\
y\left( x \right) &= -\frac{\exp\left( c_{1} \right)}{2} \cdot \int \left( x + 1 \right)^{-2} + c_{2}\, \operatorname{d}x\\
y\left( x \right) &= -\frac{\exp\left( c_{1} \right)}{2} \cdot \left[ -\left( x + 1 \right)^{-1} + c_{2} \cdot x + c_{3} \right]\\
y\left( x \right) &= -\frac{\exp\left( c_{1} \right)}{2} \cdot \left[ -\frac{1}{x + 1} + c_{2} \cdot x + c_{3} \right]\\
y\left( x \right) &= \underbrace{\frac{\exp\left( c_{1} \right)}{2}}_{\text{constant}} \cdot \frac{1}{x + 1} + \underbrace{-\frac{\exp\left( c_{1} \right)}{2} \cdot c_{2}}_{\text{constant}} \cdot x + \underbrace{-\frac{\exp\left( c_{1} \right)}{2} \cdot c_{3}}_{\text{constant}}\\
y\left( x \right) &= c_{4} \cdot \frac{1}{x + 1} + c_{5} \cdot x + c_{6}\\
\end{align*}
$$

$$\fbox{$y\left( x \right) = c_{4} \cdot \frac{1}{x + 1} + c_{5} \cdot x + c_{6}$}$$

With the condition $y\left( 1 \right) = \frac{1}{2}$ we get:
$$
\begin{align*}
y\left( 1 \right) &= c_{4} \cdot \frac{1}{1 + 1} + c_{5} \cdot 1 + c_{6}\\
\frac{1}{2} &= c_{4} \cdot \frac{1}{2} + c_{5} + c_{6}\\
\frac{1}{2} &= \frac{1}{2} \cdot c_{4} + c_{5} + c_{6}\\
\end{align*}
$$